# <object variable or with block variable not set> Run-Time error 91

Tags: vba, excel, visio

I'm creating a macro that automatically creates a visio diagram from an excel spreadsheet where the diagram is representative of connections in a row on the excel spreadsheet. I'm getting this error  and i can't find out the reason, be aware i am reasonably inexperienced at vba. My problem arises when i try to place connections between two objects that have already been placed. to call these objects again i am trying to use their unique id's but for some reason i can't get past the first hurdle.

if theres any insight you can offer to help i'd be glad, forgive the messy code!

```
    While Current_Row < Last_Row

    While current_object <= counter
        object = "Ellipse." & current_object


        Set ShpObj = AppVisio.ActivePage.Shapes(object)

        If ShpObj.Text = Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(Current_Row, COLUMN2).Value Then

            While current_get <= counter
                object = "Ellipse." & current_get


                ShpObj2 = AppVisio.ActivePage.Shapes(object)

                If ShpObj2.Text = Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(Current_Row, COLUMN2).Value Then

                    ShpObj2.AutoConnect ShpObj, visioAutoconnecDirRight, connector '(setting the color and label)

                    Set ShpObj2 = Nothing
                End If
                current_get = current_get + 1
            Wend
        End If

    current_object = current_object + 1
    current_get = 1


    Set ShpObj = Nothing
    Wend
```

So thats the block thats causing the issue, if you'd like to see the rest of the modules you can find it in a forum post here http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=4633.0

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're forgetting to properly **set** `ShpObj2`, and then you're using it in the conditional statement.

Try replacing the line

`ShpObj2 = AppVisio.ActivePage.Shapes(object)`

with:

`Set ShpObj2 = AppVisio.ActivePage.Shapes(object)`

Comment: Set ShpObj2 is set as a public variable in another module, the problem doesnt arise there though it arises with the first ShpObj
    Set ShpObj = AppVisio.ActivePage.Shapes(object)

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem that arises? Is there an exception?

Comment: when the whole macro runs it get to the code above and error91 occurs and i cant figure out why, all the variables i am using have been publicly declared within my main module, the error arises on line 4 of the code above and im pretty sure it will arise again on line 8 if it could get past that. what the code above is supposed to do is to get the current row of the spreadsheet and search through all the shapes on the sheet until it finds the text inside the shape = the text in th cell it is looking at and then do the same again but looking for the text in

Comment: if you would like to see the other modules, in case the problem arises in them it is on this forum http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=4633.0 i have also included in the file that i posted here an example spreadsheet, the connections is the label of the connector and the two sets of names are the objects to be connected